# Style inherited control like base control

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance

In WPF/C# I want to define a new class inheriting from an existing control, but which uses the style of the base control. For example:

```
class MyComboBox : ComboBox
{
    void MyExtraMethod(){...}
}
```

I dynamically switch to Luna style by doing:

```
 var uri = new Uri("/PresentationFramework.Luna;V3.0.0.0;31bf3856ad364e35;component\\themes/Luna.normalcolor.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
 var r = new ResourceDictionary();
 r.Source = uri;
 this.Resources = r;
```

While this correctly styles all instances of `ComboBox` with Luna themes, the `MyComboBox` control ends up with the Classic theme. How do I make `MyComboBox` inherit its style from `ComboBox`?

I am writing all my WPF in code, without using XAML markup. I suspect the `Style` and `BasedOn` properties are relevant, but I haven't managed to figure out exactly how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following seems to work:

```
public class MyComboBox : ComboBox
{
    public MyComboBox()
    {
        SetResourceReference(Control.StyleProperty, typeof(ComboBox));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want custom control to inherit theme template of base control, you have to

1. **`Override defaultStyleKey metadata`** in static constructor of MyComboBox.
2. Declare default template of your custom control under **`Themes/Generic.xaml`** folder and make sure it's based on style of ComboBox.
3. You need to add Luna theme as resource dictionary under **`Themes/Generic.xaml`** merged dictionaries.

**Declaration:**

```
public class MyComboBox : ComboBox
{
    static MyComboBox()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyComboBox),
                           new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyComboBox)));
    }
}
```

**Themes/Generic.xaml**:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespace"> <-- Replace namespace here
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary 
   Source="/PresentationFramework.Luna;component/themes/Luna.NormalColor.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <Style TargetType="local:MyComboBox"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}"/>

</ResourceDictionary>
```